# Can Tzara'at appear on Mitzvah apparel?

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah, clothing, tzaraas-negaim

Was it possible for Tzara'at to appear on Tefillin/Tefillin straps, which theoretically one could argue clothes the person? Or on Tzitzis, or Kohanic garments, like the Tzitz, or other clothing items designated for Mitzvah use (like the Chalitza shoe)?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think these would be different from any other piece of clothing?

Comment: Note that tefillin straps (though, technically, not the battim) have to be dyed black, and dyed leather garments aren't susceptible to tzaraas (Rambam, Hil. Negaim 13:1). The tzitz is a golden plate, which isn't subject to tzaraas either.

Comment: @Meir a) the straps could get afflicted on their reverse sides which don't need to be colored, b) do they really need to be dyed black if they are somehow naturally black?, c) the tzitz has wool strings coming off it (though they are dyed)

Comment: @DoubleAA (a) If a garment is dyed on one side but not the other, it is subject to tzaraas on the undyed side? Could be, but a source would be nice. (b) Considering that they require dyeing לשמה, probably yes, although again I don't know of a source one way or the other. (c) Those strings (even if they weren't dyed) aren't necessarily the width of a gris.

Comment: @Meir Dyeing isn't the right word. Tefillin straps must be colored. There is no tradition of dyeing them (not that dyeing would be invalid) but rather of painting one side of them. Rambam 12:10,13 sounds like only the colored part of the object is exempt  היה כולו צבוע, ובו פס אחד לבן אפילו כגריס, ונראה בו נגע--יסגיר

Comment: @DoubleAA Not a solid proof, since that פס אחד is (presumably) white all the way through, as usual with dyed cloth. (Did they even have the ability then to dye only one side?)

Comment: @Meir who cares which dimension isn't white all the way through

Comment: Bigdei Kehuna atoned for such sins ,see Zevachim 88b ,and the clothing didn't really belong to the Kohanim ,some say they weren't chayiv in tiztzis for that reason